# Struct Initialization and Printing in C

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm working on a problem involving the code below, and I'm a bit lost.
What is "class[]" doing, and how does that change how I would print the members? I've never seen an initialization like this before.

```
int main(){    
    struct Student {    
        char Initials2[2];    
        int id;    
        struct Student *teammate;    
    };    
    typedef struct Student SType;    
    #define XYpt &class[0]    
    #define ABpt &class[1]    
    #define RSpt &class[2]    
    #define CDpt &class[3]    
    #define JVpt &class[4]    
    #define RYpt &class[5]    
    SType class[6] = {    
        {{'X','Y'},123, RSpt},    
        {{'A','B'},23, RYpt},    
        {{'R','S'},11, XYpt},    
        {{'C','D'},44, JVpt},    
        {{'J','V'},42, CDpt},    
        {{'R','Y'},457, ABpt}    
    };    

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: This is an *array definition* with initializer. `int x[6] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };` means that `x` is an array of 6 `int`s and the members of the braced list are initializers for each member of the array

Answer (score 1):

**What the code does:**

- `struct Student` is a bit special, as it is containing a pointer to an object of the same type `struct Student *teammate`. This is possible by using a pointer to an object with the "struct tag" `Student`, which acts as a form of forward declaration.
- `typedef struct Student SType;` just hides away the `struct` keyword, which is a coding style matter. It would have been cleaner to write the whole thing like this:

  ```
  typedef struct Student {    
      char Initials2[2];    
      int id;    
      struct Student *teammate;    
  } SType;
  ```
- `SType class[6] = {  {{'X','Y'},123, RSpt},  ....` is just an array of 6 structs, each initialized. The bunch of macros expand to variable addresses of the same array named "class". This is poor style - the programmer used this as a dirty way to "name" each item in the array. The postfix "pt" seems to mean pointer.

---

**How the code could have been written:**

Rather than using ugly macros, it is possible to associate each item of an array with an identifier, by using a `union`. For example:

```
typedef union
{
  struct foo
  {
    int foo;
    int bar;
  } foo;
  int array [2];
} foobar;
```

Here, an object `foobar fb;` can be accessed as `fb.foo.foo` or `fb.array[0]` and it means the same item 0 of the array. With modern standard C, we can drop the inner struct name (*anonymous struct*) and just access the objects as `fb.foo`.

Also, this can be combined with *designated initializers* to initialized certain named members of the struct by their name: `foobar fb { .foo = 1, .bar = 2 };`.

Rewriting your example by using unions, anonymous struct and designated initializers, we get this instead:

```
typedef struct student {    
  char initials [2];    
  int id;    
  struct student *teammate;    
} s_type;    

typedef union
{
  struct
  {
    s_type XY;
    s_type AB;
    s_type RS;
    s_type CD;
    s_type JV;
    s_type RY;
  };
  s_type array [6];
} class_t;

class_t class = 
{
  .XY = { .initials={'X','Y'}, .id=123, .teammate = &class.RS},
  .AB = { .initials={'A','B'}, .id= 23, .teammate = &class.RY},    
  .RS = { .initials={'R','S'}, .id= 11, .teammate = &class.XY},    
  .CD = { .initials={'C','D'}, .id= 44, .teammate = &class.JV},    
  .JV = { .initials={'J','V'}, .id= 42, .teammate = &class.CD},    
  .RY = { .initials={'R','Y'}, .id=457, .teammate = &class.AB},
};
```

This is much easier to read and understand. Plus we can still use it as an array with `class.array[i]` if we want.